# Dict to string error

Tags: python, string, mongodb, dictionary, pymongo

I am trying to get hash from redis and store it into mongoDB database

```
import pymongo
//mongoDB, redis connection etc 'r' is redis object
data = r.hget('temp', 'temp')
db.collection.insert(data)
```

I am getting this pymongo error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "try.py", line 45, in <module>
    collection.insert(data)
  File "/home/amitt001/mycodes/clay/proj-1/envplay/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 1926, in insert
    check_keys, manipulate, write_concern)
  File "/home/amitt001/mycodes/clay/proj-1/envplay/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 430, in _insert
    gen(), check_keys, self.codec_options, sock_info)
  File "/home/amitt001/mycodes/clay/proj-1/envplay/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 405, in gen
    doc['_id'] = ObjectId()
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

How data is of type string? While doing:

```
print data

{'offsite/domains': 1, 'scheduler/dequeued': 104, 'log_count/INFO': 7, 'downloader/response_count': 104, 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 2, 9, 42, 34, 128090), 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 104, 'offsite/filtered': 2, 'scheduler/enqueued': 104, 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 2, 9, 42, 53, 894133), 'downloader/request_bytes': 43108, 'request_depth_max': 4}

print(type(data))
<type 'str'>
```

Why mongoDB is not storing the dict? How dict on type check converts to string?

EDIT:
output of

```
data = ast.literal_eval(data)
print data, type(data)
print(repr(data))
```

[image]

Comment: @user3100115 its a pymongo variable. Not defined by me in the code. See `File "/home/amitt001/mycodes/clay/proj-1/envplay/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 405, in gen
    doc['_id'] = ObjectId()`
In mongoDb '_id' is the primary key. So it is trying to set the primary key and the object that I am trying to store somehow magically gets converted to type str it is giving me error that string is immutable.

Answer (score 1):

You variable `data` is string. you need to convert it to python dictionary. That is what 
[**`ast.literal_eval`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) does.

```
import ast
data = r.hget('temp', 'temp')
db.collection.insert(ast.literal_eval(data))
```

---

The result of `print(data)` is expected.

```
>>> data = "{'foo': 1, 'bar': 1}"
>>> print(data)
{'foo': 1, 'bar': 1}
>>> d = {'foo': 1, 'bar': 1}
>>> print(d)
{'foo': 1, 'bar': 1}
>>> type(data)
<class 'str'>
>>> type(d)
<class 'dict'>
```

As you can see `data` is string and `d` is dictionary but using [**`print`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=print#print) we get the same output.

Comment: Thank you, I already looked at this method.  I am sure there is some bug with redis. The same commands result into dict type object in console but in the python code it is of type str. I am getting irritated. It doesn't solve my problem but i'm upvoting your answer, might help someone.

Comment: yeah it is <type 'str'> but print(data) result into dict type object. Also, I tried json.dumps, json.loads, ast.literal_eval, even nested json.loads(json.dumps(data)) still `print(data) == <type 'str'>`

Comment: because data contains datetime i first did json.dumps() ast.literal_eval(json.dumps(a, default=json_util.default)) but again error